# How to correctly receive data via serial port?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I make two applications, one to send (arduino) and one to receive data (using C#). I'm almost sure, that sending application works good, I can see the data in program like Putty (it can watch serial port).

My receiving program is nothing special. I took the code from Microsoft's site:

```
private readonly SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
_serialPort.Parity=Parity.None;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

private static void DataReceivedHandler(
            object sender,
            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    _testString = indata;
    Console.WriteLine(_testString);
}
```

The data example is: y5-1

In Putty (or other program to watch serial port) I can see "y5-1", but in my program data is like:
"y5-\n
1"

I mean, there is newline too fast. Data is sending in loop with delay 500 ms, so sending is not too fast.

Anyone know how should I write receive code?

Comment: That is what happens when you use ReadExisting().  An aptly named method, you only get the data that is **existing** in the receive buffer.  Usually only one or two characters.  Use ReadLine() instead.

Comment: Wow, it works. Thank you.